# RestAssured getBody after Post Request

Tags: java, post, rest-assured

I'm working on the POST request to get a better understanding of RestAssured on the website https://reqres.in/

```
@Test
public void postTest() {                        
    Response response = RestAssured.given()
                                    .body("{\"name\": \"morpheus\"}"
                                            + "{\"job\": \"leader\"}")
                                    .when()
                                    .post(base_URI);
    assertEquals(response.statusCode(), 201);
    System.out.println(response.asPrettyString());
}
```

The `status code` is `201` which is I expected, I want to print out the JSON data that I just POST by using `response.asPrettyString()`

But the data returned is

```
{
    "id": "302",
    "createdAt": "2022-08-23T21:47:44.857Z"
}
```

instad of

```
{
    "name": "morpheus",
    "job": "leader",
    "id": "324",
    "createdAt": "2022-08-23T21:47:21.176Z"
}
```

What should I do to get the full JSON data?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that isn't the full JSON data? Maybe the issue is your server?

I also noticed an issue in the JSON body. I would assume this is the payload you want to send?

```
{
  "name": "morpheus",
  "job":  "leader"
}
```

I don't think there is anything wrong with your test code other than the JSON, but you can get restAssured to log the response payload and do the assertions...

```
  @Test
  public void postTest() {
    RestAssured.given()
        .body("{"
            + "\"name\": \"morpheus\","
            + "\"job\": \"leader\""
            + "}")
        .when()
        .post(base_URI)
        .then().log().body()
        .and().assertThat().statusCode(201);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you forgot add `content-type=application/json` to header. The correct code would be:

```
Response response = RestAssured.given()
        .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
        .body("{\n" +
                "    \"name\": \"morpheus\",\n" +
                "    \"job\": \"leader\"\n" +
                "}")
        .when()
        .post("https://reqres.in/api/users");
assertEquals(response.statusCode(), 201);
response.prettyPrint();
```

Result:

```
{
    "name": "morpheus",
    "job": "leader",
    "id": "257",
    "createdAt": "2022-08-24T02:48:40.444Z"
}
```